# Menu is getting cut off while scrolling

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, responsive-design

The top menu is getting cut off while scrolling down.
http://freshpotsolutions.com/saudisurgeons.com/test9/
I would like to keep the same width for the header throughout.

Comment: Post some code and/or a jsFiddle. This is quite impractical.

Comment: what you want to do on scroll? show full menu?

Comment: remove this 'overflow:hidden' from '.theme-layout.boxed' class

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `overflow:hidden`  from `.theme-layout.boxed` class which will show full menu on scroll

Comment: But when I am doing it, it looks ugly on bigger screen. Can't I make a fixed width for that container. Please see the screenshot below.
http://freshpotsolutions.com/saudisurgeons.com/test9/images/screenshot.jpg

Comment: you can give width to the container so that they stays in the middle

Comment: could you please tell me to which class shud i specify the width ?

Comment: this class   .business1 .container { width: xxx }

Comment: Sir, the above step was useful but, when we scroll to the bottom of the page, there is a white bg appearing on the header container which is spoiling. http://freshpotsolutions.com/saudisurgeons.com/test11/